# Entity framework models with Web API that don't extend Entity

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

I've noticed a lot of github project using models that extend Entity.

I'm following a tutorial and it doesn't do this. Its just a plain class.

```
public class Seller
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string URL { get; set; }
    }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-4

Then here I found models that extend Entity:

https://github.com/IshtiaqueIrteza/Movie-Review-website/blob/master/BackEnd/Movie%20Review%20Website/MRWEntity/Category.cs

Are there multiple version of EF and which one should I use if I'm working with Web API?

Answer (score 0):

Entity class which exists in the github repository you provide, is just a base class for entities created by hand. It is up to you creating a base model or not for all your entities.

Of course there are multiple versions of EF but it is not related with your question here.

Comment: I have been using EF without install any packages, why does this tutorial say to install it: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-web-api-crud-logics-using-entity-framework-without-writing-single-code/

Comment: Entity framework comes with seperate package, so you need to install it. Are you sure you did not install any package? Can you check it from nuget manager?

Comment: No I started a web api project and it was already there, im using visual studio 2017